# Sorting by count() of pivot table Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm creating a voting based website in Laravel 4. I have a many-to-many relationship between Users and post_votes(). my post_votes table has a user_id, post_id, and vote field (0 or 1 for up and down). I want to order my posts by total votes, upvotes, and downvotes. any thoughts?

Comment: The basic idea is to join the votes table on your posts table, and order the query on up or down. Have you tried anything yet? Some code will help to get answers :)

Comment: @RobGordijn I think he is trying to do this with Eloquent, judging by the tag he used when creating the question.

Comment: I ended up kinda going around Eloquent. I was hoping to do it clear but here is what I ended up doing. 
`$posts=Post::all();
$post_array= array();
 foreach($posts as $post){
  $post_array[]=array('id'=>$post->id, 'votes'=>$post->votes->count());
 }

 function votes($a, $b) {
     return $a['votes'] - $b['votes'];
 }

 
 usort($post_array,'votes');
 $obj_array=array();
 
 foreach($post_array as $post){
  $obj_array[]=Post::find($post['id']);
 } 
 
 $posts= $obj_array;`

Comment: Great that it worked for you, one thing you might consider is inspecting the SQL query log to make sure there aren't extra queries being executed for counting the data that might hurt your application's performance.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a change in your table structure. The simplest thing you should do is create a field in your tables to store the total number of votes and increment it every time a user gets a vote. This will not only allow you to sort by the votes count, but will also improve the performance of your application, because the there will be no need to re-scan the table to find out what the count is.